# Ginkgo to cobertura and JUnit

Tags: go, junit, cobertura, ginkgo, shippable-ci

I am using Shippable as my CI and my project is based on Go 1.11. All the unit tests are written in BDD style using Ginkgo and Gomega. In my test pipeline, I have something like:

```
gocov test ./... | gocov-xml > shippable/codecoverage/coverage.xml
go test -v ./... | go-junit-report > shippable/testresults/junitresults.xml
```

This will create the coverage file in Cobertura format and unit test report in JUnit format.

In my project, we have multiple test suites. I am planning to use Ginkgo CLI to perform coverage and unit test instead of `gocov` and `go test`. Something like:

```
ginkgo -r -cover -outputdir=./shippable/codecoverage/ -coverprofile=coverage.txt
ginkgo -r -focus="\[Unit\]" -outputdir=./shippable/testresults/ -coverprofile=unit.txt
```

Now the problem is that I am unable to convert the coverage.txt file to equivalent Cobertura format XML file (which shippable will require) and unit.txt file to equivalent JUnit XML file.

I've seen [how to generate the JUnit file from a test suite](https://onsi.github.io/ginkgo/#generating-junit-xml-output) but in my project, we have multiple test suite, which will result in multiple JUnit files, which I don't want.

Any idea, how can I convert and use them?

Answer (score 1):

To create the Cobertura format:

Nevermind, figured out myself.

Generate the cover using covermode as set

`ginkgo -r -cover -covermode=set -outputdir=shippable/codecoverage/ -coverprofile=coverage.out`

Now, we need to remove duplicate entries of `mode: set`

`awk '!seen[$0]++' shippable/codecoverage/coverage.out > shippable/codecoverage/coverage-fix.out`

Finally, convert to Cobertura

`bash gocov convert shippable/codecoverage/coverage-fix.out | gocov-xml > shippable/codecoverage/coverage.xml`